# Differentiate $\sqrt{x} e^x \sec x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Differentiate the following equation : $$\sqrt{x} e^x \sec x$$

Here I can see 3 values.

1. $\sqrt{x}$
2. $e^x$
3. $\sec x$

This time, how can I use product rule?

My book said

$$\sqrt{x} \frac{d}{dx}(e^x \sec (x)) + e^x \sec {x} \frac{d}{dx} (\sqrt{x})$$

But, I found three values. So, according to product rule if I differentiate than, I would have 3 variable, wouldn't I? What am I missing?

$$\frac{d}{dx}ab = a\frac{d}{dx}b + b\frac{d}{dx}a$$

It's for two values (a,b). So, It would have 3 variables for 3 values(a,b,c).

Comment: Which product rule are you referring to? Where do those "3 variable" come into play? Can you quote it exactly?

Comment: @Gae.S. I have edited my question...

Comment: The product rule for derivatives works in the natural way. If you have $f(x)\cdot g(x)$, then $(f\cdot g)’=f’g+g’f$. Now, if $g$ itself is the product of two functions, then you apply the product rule to $g’$ in the formula for the original product rule.

Comment: It's for two functions, not for two variables. $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is one function and $g(x) = e^x \sec x$ is another function.

Comment: @Clayton So, I should take $$e^x sec(x)$$ as an function and, $$\sqrt{x}$$ as another function?

Comment: @Istiak Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @TobyMak But, why they won't be 3 functions? As they have 3 x values...

Comment: It just doesn't work with 3 functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I had read a formula in my book which I forgot while solving the differentiation.

$$\frac{d}{dx} (xyz) = xy \frac{d}{dx} z + xz \frac{d}{dx} y + yz\frac{d}{dx} x$$

That's product rule for 3 functions. You can apply the rules in thousand of functions also. Here's a easy way to remember it

> $$\frac{d}{dx} (multiplication.of.thousand.of.functions) = multiplication.of.other.functions\frac{d}{dx} first function +multiplication.of.other.functions \frac{d}{dx} second function+.................$$

If you follow [the rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4189254/876873) also, you will get same value.

Answer (score 4):

The product rule, which I'll write as $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$, works *recursively*. That is, if you have a product of *three* functions, for example, then

$$(fgh)'=(f(gh))'=f'(gh)+f(gh)'=f'(gh)+f(g'h+gh')=f'gh+fg'h+fgh'$$

In your specific case, you have $f(x)=\sqrt x$, $g(x)=e^x$, and $h(x)=\sec x$, so you just need to differentiate each of those functions separately and then fit the results into the final formula for the derivative of the product.

Remark: The use of parentheses here is potentially confusing but hopefully clear from context: the parentheses in $f(gh)$ and elsewhere in the displayed equation are purely for multiplicative grouping, whereas the parentheses in $f(x)=\sqrt x$ (and likewise for $g(x)$ and $h(x)$) are part of defining $f$, $g$ and $h$ as functions of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Logarithmic differentiation allows you to derivate the three terms together:

$$y =\sqrt{x} e^x \sec x $$
$$ log\; y = log(\sqrt{x})+log(e^x)+log(\sec x) $$
....
$$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{1}{2x}+1+ \tan x $$
$$ y'= \sqrt{x} e^x \sec x \cdot\left(\frac{1}{2x}+1+ \tan x \right)$$
$$ = ....$$

Answer (score 1):

> Here I can see 3 values.
>
> 1. $\sqrt{x}$
> 2. $e^x$
> 3. $\sec x$

No- those are three *functions.*

The product rule is a rule that tells us how to differentiate the product of two *functions*.

The question is to differentiate $\sqrt{x} e^x \sec x$.

To do this, write:

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \left(\ \sqrt{x} e^x \sec x\ \right) $$

$$= \frac{d}{dx} \left(\ \left(\sqrt{x}\right) \left(e^x \sec x\right)\ \right) \overset{\mbox{Product rule}}{=} \left(\ \frac{d}{dx} \left(\sqrt{x}\right)\right)\cdot \left(e^x \sec x\right)\ + \sqrt{x}\ \cdot \frac{d}{dx}\left(\ e^x \sec x\right)\ $$

$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)$ is easy to calculate, so the only thing you have to deal with now is the term $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ e^x \sec x\right),\ $ but you can use the product rule to calculate this...